# What if it turns out that a question was actually missing the point?

Tags: discussion, edits, questions

### Innocent beginnings

The generic situation is that [a very broad question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/73438/new-mountain-bike-feels-sticky-or-grinding-when-pedaling) was asked. Someone was trying to troubleshoot a problem in a situation where they only have limited knowledge.

It was about bikes which is probably a good generic example because the same can probably happen on most sites. Everybody knows what a bike is. Not everyone knows what, say, Unix or GIS is.

### Twist plot

The asker then made a discovery that pinpointed the problem. In other words, it narrowed the question down massively.

In the example above, this is only admitted in an exchange of comments under an answer - this in itself is probably an issue.

Effectively, it turns out that the original question was actually missing the point. On one hand, the asker has found what part caused the problem, so the question is more or less answered. On the other hand, his bike is still broken.

### Where does this story go?

**How should such questions be handled?**

Broadly, I can think of the following ways:

1. Question is overhauled - It is edited thoroughly so that it now asks about the specific, newly discovered problem. But this may render some answers silly.
2. An answer is added, which explains which part was playing up, and this gets marked as the solution. A new question is asked about the newly discovered, specific issue. But if we go this way we could end up with lots of questions which are "solved, but not really solved". Is this really the spirit of Stack Exchange? "If you ask a broad question, the answers are only going to direct you to a solution, but not give it to you"?

Is there a better way to deal with this? It's probably a matter of balancing the different principles of SE, isn't it? If we say that all broad questions are bad questions, we're probably not going to get many questions at all.

Comment: @Rob I do expect that a similar questions exists but I don't think it's any of the three you suggested: 1. If anything, it seems the opposite of **XY** (XY is too specific, my case is too broad). 2. Turning the question into a **chameleon** is more or less option 1 in my OP but the issue with this is so obvious even I noticed it. I think it's a situation that could turn into a chameleon question if not nipped in the bud. 3. The **frame challenge** question remains open-ish and seems almost like an **XY** approach to my question. Please let me know if you think I should add all this into my OP.

Comment: On StackOverflow such questions are often closed as the site specific reason "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". It covers the situation you outlined - the description of the close reason reads: "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." - if I were to put this in bike terms it would be like asking why the bike stays in one place even if the asker was pushing the pedals. If it turns out the bike is missing a chain, then it's not really a useful resolution for future visitors.

Comment: Nobody should answer if he or she isn't sure what the answer is. It's a strong hint that the question is still too broad. The network isn't really a general purpose troubleshooting service. If the asker can't really pinpoint the problem sufficiently, nobody can answer it really. Still some people may try. A quick close might be for the best there.

Answer (score 8):

My understanding is that Stack Exchange sites are designed for focused Q&A.

Consequently, I think that broad questions should be closed as needing more focus.

I think that the best way to find a solution for a broad question, that you are thinking about asking, is to break it down into a series of focused questions that you then ask as a series of separate questions.

Focused questions lead to much less convoluted Q&A than the broad questions that lead you to ask your question here.

Comment: The problem is that the original broad question was not really a bad one, it's more like the issue is not what the OP thought. _I think that the best way to find a solution for a broad question, that you are thinking about asking, is to break it down into a series of focused questions that you then ask as a series of separate questions._ - sure, my question is what to do if that broad question has been asked already.

Comment: @pateksan If I see a question that is too broad for focused Q&A then I vote to close it.  The only alternative to that which I would normally use is to edit it to make it sufficiently focused, without stranding any existing answers.